# X++ reports not generating over batch

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

When trying to generate X++ reports over batch, 
these fail to generate, and say that the report is empty.

I was told that in AX2012, it is impossible to create X++ reports over batch, is this true?
If not, how can I make sure my reports will generate over batch?

Comment: How do your reports fail? Check your batch history for errors. Any execution at all?

Comment: The reports are empty and thus not generated. The method containing all the calls to reportrun.execute(#controlnumber) is never executed. I debugged on serverside, and the breakpoints in these method never get hit. After so called generation, nothing is generated, and I get an infolog stating that the report is empty...

Comment: Don't forget that when running in batch you are executing from the server.  Test if your underlying helper classes etc can run in the same way, and not only from the client.

Comment: It runs perfectly in client-batch, but in server-batch it refuses to call the report class, only running in the RunBaseReport class.